# Dividing day times into intervals in R for NYC Taxi data

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the NYC taxi data. So, I am trying to divide the pickup times into 1 hour intervals using R . Could anyone help me an efficient way of doing it?

```
    head(data$dropoff_datetime)
[1] 2013-01-01 15:18:10 2013-01-06 00:22:54 2013-01-05 18:54:23 2013-01-07 23:58:20 2013-01-07 23:34:24 2013-01-07 15:38:37
```

So, in the present state, the data is of the form , "day time". What I want to do is that trim off the date and make a new column in the dataframe data with values from {0,1,...,23} depending on the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `hour` of the package `lubridate` like that

```
require(lubridate)
hour(ymd_hms(data$dropoff_datetime))
```

`hour` taking as argument any date time objects.